# IOS: fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock not called when no internet connection

Tags: ios, swift3, cloudkit, ckerror

I'm using the CloudKit in my app. To retrieve all changes from the iCloud I use the operation CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation. When I add this operation while I do not have an active internet connection the fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock is never called.

I do expect that this completion block is called with an error CKError.networkUnavailable.

I'm using swift 3.

I probably misunderstand some things. Can someone explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CKOperation Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckoperation)

> CKOperation objects have a default quality of service level of
>   NSQualityOfServiceUtility. Operations at this
>   level are considered discretionary, and are scheduled by the system
>   for an optimal time based on battery level and other factors. On
>   iPhone, discretionary activities are paused when Low Power Mode is
>   enabled.

What you need to do is manually set your `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation`'s QoS to `.userInitiated`

```
// userInitiated: Used for performing work that has been explicitly requested by the user,
// and for which results must be immediately presented in order to allow for further user interaction.
// For example, loading an email after a user has selected it in a message list.
//
// set to userInitiated make sure the completion with error will immediately returned if currently no internet connection
zoneOperation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
```